# Is is safe to use Response.StatusCode = 301 in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I'm developing a website and I want to implement a permanent redirect on one of my controllers for social networks, so for example somebody enters domain.com/facebook, the Facebook controller Index method sets the Response.StatusCde = 301 and the RedirectLocation to the users Facebook page; so the visitor id sent to Facebook.

After some discussion, some guys think this is unsafe to do and was wondering if there was an MVC method call to do this - rather than use the Response object.

Is it safe/practical to use the Response object in this way?

I've asked Google but it seems to return nothing specific to my problem :\

Comment: Safe in what respect? For SEO purposes?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [RedirectPermanent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384856.aspx) for redirecting safely (to prevent SEO bombing, etc), by doing something like:

```
return RedirectPermanent("url-here");
```

This will correctly do what you are looking for, by returning a 301 status code that Google will acknowledge.